# web.config file line denies access to Google OAuth login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

In the web.config file the line:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

denies access to the Google OAuth login (using OAuthWebSecurity).
When we comment those lines it works, but someone said here those lines are required for security reasons.

Is there any other way to make Google OAuth login work without commenting those lines?

Comment: I don't see the relation between Google OAuth and ASP.NET Authentication

Answer (score 0):

I got OAuth without any of that code :P (Using PHP)

This following code uses OAuth2.0 to authenticate the connection, it creates an event on a selectable google calendar of your picking, with a simple form to add the  event specifics.

After testing I have this working & also a different version whereby the event details are passed in as variables via an external form and the connection is using a service account rather than OAuth2.0

Good Luck.

```
<?php
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Event Creator");

$client->setClientId('YOUR CLI ID HERE.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR CLI SECRET HERE');
$client->setRedirectUri('THIS FILE LOCATION HERE');
$client->setDeveloperKey('API key here');

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])){
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])){
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()){
$calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == "addCalEvent"){
$title = $_POST["title"];
$desc = $_POST["desc"];
$calID = $_POST["calID"];
$locat = $_POST["locat"];
$from = $_POST["from"];
$until = $_POST["until"];

//Set the Event data
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary($title);
$event->setDescription($desc);
$event->setLocation($locat);
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($from);
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($until);
$event->setEnd($end);

$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('YOUR CALENDAR ID HERE@group.calendar.google.com', $event);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
}
}

print "<div style='width:100%;height:100%;'><div style='width:550px;height:320px;text-align:center;margin:200px auto;background-color:#f0ffff;border:1px solid black;'><div style='padding:50px;'><table>";
print "<form action='caladd.php' method='POST'>";
print "<tr><td>Title: </td><td><input type='text' name='title' id='title'></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>Desc: </td><td><input type='text' name='desc' id='desc'></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>Location: </td><td><input type='text' name='locat' id='locat'></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td colspan='2'>Date Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS(.000)-00:00 (.000 = Optional)</td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>From: </td><td><input type='text' name='from' id='from'></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>To: </td><td><input type='text' name='until' id='until'></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>Select Calendar: </td><td><select name='calID' id='chooseCal'>";
for($i=0; $i < count($calList['items']); $i++)
{
print "<option value=".$calList['items'][$i]['id']."'>".$calList['items'][$i]['summary']."</option>";

}
print "</select></br></td></tr>";
print "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='addCalEvent'>";
print "<tr><td colspan='2'><div style='text-align:right;'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div></td></tr>";
print "</form>";
print "</table></div></div></div>";

$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
else
{
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Create a Google Calendar Event?</a>";
print "<a href='/'>Exit to Homepage</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: on second thought, reading your question... I understand I misinterpreted it... I wouldn't know about the web.config file without looking. What is this for?

Comment: I appreciate your effort bro. What I'm asking is about ASP .NET's configuration file web.config. Seeing your code. I kinda miss PHP :)

Comment: I just started learning it on my own accord from online video tutorials whilst at work :P

Lol, I went from knowing 0 PHP to programming a custom Google Maps JSON -> API -> XML -> Custom Google Map results.... That was a killer!

Since then I have just become really fond with PHP, I think its PHPantastic, *Oh dear*, the terrible punn's I think of.

I like mixing PHP with JS, HTML & CSS to make some really cool dynamic content, and the best part being that PHP is hidden to the user!